# TopLink with JPA taking more connections

Tags: jpa, connection, toplink

In my application we are using Toplink with Jpa.
Here the problem is we are using stored procedures in this application, we are taking the connection using Jndi connection for Stored Procedure calling, and we are using EntityManger for remaining queries. But here if we launching the application it is taking two connections from connection pool. After the application launching I am calling the Stored Procedure(sp)
one sp I am taking one connection but in websphere connection pool it is creating two connections?
can U plese help me how to overcome this problem.....

I won't using JTA, to get the JDBC connection I am using

EntityManager em = getJpaTemplate().getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();

this way I am getting the JDBC Connection...and I configured the persitence.xml file following code...

```
<properties>
    <property name="toplink.logging.level" value="OFF"/>
    <property name="toplink.cache.type.default" value="NONE"/>
    <property name="com.thoughtinc.runtime.persistence.sql.syntax" value="db2" />
</properties>
```

So, please kindly look into this and tell me any if I am doing any wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using JTA or non-JTA?  Are you releasing the connection back to the pool after using it?

Depending on your configuration (include your persistence.xml), if you have a non-JTA login configured TopLink may use this for non-transactional read queries.  This is configurable in your persistence.xml.

To get the JDBC Connection from a TopLink (EclipseLink) EntityManager use em.unwrap(Connection.class)

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your reply.

I won't using JTA, to get the JDBC connection I am using

EntityManager em = getJpaTemplate().getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();

this way I am getting the JDBC Connection...and I configured the persitence.xml file following code...

    <properties>
        <property name="toplink.logging.level" value="OFF"/>
  <property name="toplink.cache.type.default" value="NONE"/>
  <property name="com.thoughtinc.runtime.persistence.sql.syntax" value="db2" />
 </properties>
   
So, please kindly look into this and tell me any if I am doing any wrong here.